# Change AutoCompleteTextView hint programmatically

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu

I have a material exposed dropdown menu

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/accSetupBankContainer"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:counterOverflowTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:errorTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/filled_exposed_dropdown"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:fontFamily="@font/fira_sans"
            android:hint="@string/acc_setup_bank_ex"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:inputType="none" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Then i initialize it like this:

```
String[] banks = getBankNames();
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
        getApplicationContext(),R.layout.dropdown_menu_popup_item, banks);
AutoCompleteTextView editTextFilledExposedDropdownBanks = findViewById(R.id.filled_exposed_dropdown);
    editTextFilledExposedDropdownBanks.setAdapter(adapter);
    editTextFilledExposedDropdownBanks.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        bankName = adapter.getItem(position);
    }
});
```

and an if like this:

```
if(accEdit != null){
    ...
    editTextFilledExposedDropdownBanks.setHint(accEdit.getAccount_bank());
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, instead of replacing the hint set in the xml, it just stands underneath and when the dropdown menu is clicked the hint set in the xml is the one that behaves like an hint.

How can i change the hint by replacing the old with the new?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Call `setHint()` on the `TextInputLayout`, rather than the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Comment: It worked, post it as an answer if you want to